# prop of a kind function - get error from function catch vuejs

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vue-props

I send prop of a kind function.

this is send function prop from parent component:

```
<confirm
    v-else-if="isshowConfirm"
    class="pt-10"  
    :isRedStamp="isRedStamp"
    :onConfirm="updateDataConfirm"     
    @cancel="cancelConfirm"/>
```

this is function

```
methods:{
    updateDataConfirm(data) {
        axios.post(`/edi-certificate/${certificateId}/confirm-certificate`, {
            ...data,
        }).then(res => {
            if(res) {
                console.log('success')
            }
        }).catch(e => {             
            console.log('errrrr',e);
        })
    },
}
```

this is call function from child component:

```
props: {   
    isRedStamp: Boolean,
    onConfirm: Function,
},

methods: {
    async createCertificate() {
        await this.onConfirm(this.data)
    }
}
```

When function return error i want get in child component the error.

How doing this?

Comment: usually, you'd use use `try`/`catch` with `async`/`await` (assuming `this.onConfirm` returns a Promise of course) - you'll want to `return axios.post` for a start

Comment: thank you! I add promise and return with resolve() and reject() function

Comment: why? `axios.post` already returns a Promise ... are you using the Promise constructor anti-pattern - sure it probably works, but it's not correct